# Revalidate the whole cache from squid3 with a command

Tags: squid

Is there any way to revalidate all files in the squid cache automatically triggered by a command?

My intention is to run this as cronjob over night, because I have a lot of [refresh patterns](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/refresh_pattern/) that disable revalidation (or set the time for this very high) for certain files or domains in [my configuration](https://github.com/ypid/squid3-config) but I still want a recent version.